# How to remove these D3.js console log error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have the error below, after trying out some other work arounds (like trying out the suggested solutions to similar problem)- no success took place.

`Error: <rect> attribute height: Expected length, "NaN"`

Could someone take a look at my code and help me in changing it such that these errors disappear?

My data sample can be found [here](http://nompumelelo.me/data/story2/radio/data.csv).

[This](http://nompumelelo.me/data/InspectError.png) is how the errors used to look before getting helped from the comments.

[This](http://nompumelelo.me/data/story2/radio/errorNow.png) is how the errors currently look

Below is my js - code:

I am not using the current latest version of D3.js - instead I am using the old version 4

I am not that strong in D3.js yet (still learning).

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// The scale spacing the groups:
var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.1);

// The scale for spacing each group's bar:
var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
    .padding(0.05);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#008000", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#008080", "#ff0000", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);


   // trying to add tooltips 
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.years; }));
  x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { return d[key]; }); })]).nice();

 g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class","bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.years) + ",0)"; })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); });

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", 2)
      .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .text("ZAR");

  var legend = g.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(keys.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 17)
      .attr("width", 15)
      .attr("height", 15)
      .attr("fill", z)
      .attr("stroke", z)
      .attr("stroke-width",2)
      .on("click",function(d) { update(d) });

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 4.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .text(function(d) { return d;});


  var filtered = [];

  ////
  //// Update and transition on click:
  ////

  function update(d) {  

    //
    // Update the array to filter the chart by:
    //

    // add the clicked key if not included:
    if (filtered.indexOf(d) == -1) {
     filtered.push(d); 
      // if all bars are un-checked, reset:
      if(filtered.length == keys.length) filtered = [];
    }
    // otherwise remove it:
    else {
      filtered.splice(filtered.indexOf(d), 1);
    }

    //
    // Update the scales for each group(/years)'s items:
    //
    var newKeys = [];
    keys.forEach(function(d) {
      if (filtered.indexOf(d) == -1 ) {
        newKeys.push(d);
      }
    })
    x1.domain(newKeys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { if (filtered.indexOf(key) == -1) return d[key]; }); })]).nice();

    // update the y axis:
            svg.select(".y")
            .transition()
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
            .duration(500);


    //
    // Filter out the bands that need to be hidden:
    //
    var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar").selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })

   bars.filter(function(d) {
         return filtered.indexOf(d.key) > -1;
      })
      .transition()
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return (+d3.select(this).attr("x")) + (+d3.select(this).attr("width"))/2;  
      })
      .attr("height",0)
      .attr("width",0)     
      .attr("y", function(d) { return height; })
      .duration(500);

    //


    // Adjust the remaining bars:
    //
    bars.filter(function(d) {
        return filtered.indexOf(d.key) == -1;
      })
      .transition()
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
      .duration(500);


    // update legend:
    legend.selectAll("rect")
      .transition()
      .attr("fill",function(d) {
        if (filtered.length) {
          if (filtered.indexOf(d) == -1) {
            return z(d); 
          }
           else {
            return "white"; 
          }
        }
        else {
         return z(d); 
        }
      })
      .duration(100);

      legend.selectAll("bar")
      .text(function(d, i) { return label[i]; });


  }

});

</script>
```

Comment: I think it is related to this question 
`.attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })` could be Nan I don't know why exactly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746319/error-rect-attribute-width-expected-length-nan-and-text-attribute-dx

Comment: svg.attr("height") returns a string. parseInt(svg.attr("height")) will return a number

Comment: thanks @MichaelRovinsky  but that doesn't fix the errors

Comment: @shadysherif The scaleBand seems to be the issue - but the link shared does not solve it either. Thanks

Comment: replace
.attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
with:
.attr("height", function(d) { 
    const h =  height - y(d.value);
    console.log('HEIGHT: ', h);
    return h;})
... and check the console

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky  the console is still the same :(  Thanks for your  attempt

Comment: @eloleo if h is NaN, then either height or y(d.value) is NaN - print both of them and find out where is the problem

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky they are both said to be undefined. Thanks again.  Parsing is done already .

Comment: Check for variables that might return an array or object but are included in your mathematical expressions.

Comment: check what what is the type of the  value  returned by `y` method. If that returns an array for example, then `height - y(d.value);` will be `NaN` since `123 - [1,2,3]`, for example, is `NaN`.

Comment: Could you share some of your sample data present in data.csv?

Comment: @altocumulus Can you show the answer either way? I will edit my claim

Comment: @Coola  Data sample is now added

Comment: Your data file has unlabelled columns when I open it in Excel. i.e. there are more data points than column headers. This may cause some problems.

Comment: Your code is not able to reproduce the screenshot you showed. Could you please check the code you posted matches what you have so far?

Comment: I've got your code [running here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/uNbuB78DCBYsaJd7?open=lib%2Fscript.js) with no errors.  One thing that's suspicious though is your CSV data.  The data rows have more values than columns (7 with 6 columns).  In the sample you uploaded the first row also had 8 data values.

Comment: @Mark I think that  the  environment where you're running the code is suppressing the errors. The CSV file, Thanks for pointing it out- I made changes but the error is still there.

Comment: @Coola  The csv file with the data should be fine in as far as the columns item numbers matches with that of the rows.

Comment: @Coola  The new screenshot has the current errors - showing after the changes have been made to the data file

Comment: @elolelo, the problem is still your csv data.  Remove the 3 empty lines at the end of it.

Comment: @Mark Removing the 3 empty lines at the end of the file is not solving the problem. I have tried just not. Those 3 lines serve another purpose which has nothing to do with the error. the height and the y values - how they have been defined seems to be the error. Thanks - i suggest we leave the csv file as it is.

Comment: @elolelo, after you remove the lines, make sure your web server and/or browser is not caching the file.  It is the reason.  Here's the error [with 3 lines](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/uNbuB78DCBYsaJd7?open=lib%2Fscript.js) and error [without 3 lines](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/BlNpukxrgNivvO0o?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview).

Comment: @Mark I appreciate your efforts. Thanks... Please do me one favour, test all this in a different environment? On my side, I see errors from both of the links you shared.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201789/discussion-between-mark-and-elolelo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of this problem is extra lines at the end of the data file.  When the `d3.csv` method parses this file it'll produce a data array with extra element swhere each value is `NaN`.  The data file only really has 7 datum:

[image]

Since the OP didn't want to change the CSV file to remove these lines we can work around the bad data by removing the bad rows in the `d3.csv` callback after parsing with:

```
function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  // copy the columns since filter will remove this property
  let c = data.columns;
  // filter the data to remove the rows without a year
  data = data.filter(function(d){
    return d.years != "";
  })
  // add the columns property back in
  data.columns = c;
```

[Here's the code running correctly](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/uNbuB78DCBYsaJd7?open=lib%2Fscript.js).

Comment: Mark, how would the call back function work if we have more than one argument? See more about my current challenge in the chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201789/discussion-between-mark-and-elolelo

Answer (score 1):

There must be a problem with your `y`. Check the type of the value returned by `y`. If the value returned is an array or object, then any mathematical expression that involves it will result to `NaN` (with exemption to `+`, concatenating values as strings).

Say for example:

```
var x = 100 - [1, 2, 3] // returns NaN
var y = 100 / {} // returns NaN
```

So there might be a problem with this:

```
.attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
```